# Raspberry pi pico won’t work with battery

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico

I tried connect raspberry pi pico w with 3.7v li-ion battery but it didn’t work i tried connect it to my computer it still doesn’t work until i press run in thonny

I want raspberry pi pico w to work with 3.7v li ion battery

Comment: You don't say how you connected the battery, so we can't help very much.  If you power it from VSYS then it should work. See "4.5. Powering Pico" in the data sheet https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/pico-datasheet.pdf  Be sure to NEVER use both USB and VSYS at the same time!

Comment: Best to ask on [raspberrypi.se] - this question is unrelated to programming and is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

do you have the program named "main.py"? because this is what the pico starts by itself without hitting run when connected to thonny.

I guess you try to use the pico without a PC just on battery and it doesn't come to life? than maybe having a wrong filename for your main program could be the cause.